# Как поставить библиотеку в С++?

Tags: c++

Я пришёл с питона несколько дней назад, и для своих задач я использовал только opencv.
И вот тут я захотел попробовать C++ и как бы смешно не было, но я не нашёл даже гайдов как устанавливать библиотеки (Пролистав несколько страниц, и попробовав разные поисковые запросы и даже гайды на ютубе) Похоже это делается несколько сложнее чем в питоне.

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2019

Comment: *"Похоже это делается несколько сложнее чем в питоне."* - это еще мягко сказано... Собственно концепция "поставить библиотеку" в самом С++, как таковая, отсутствует.

Comment: Скажите операционку, и если вы на винде - еще и компилятор. Ну и на всякий случай IDE и систему сборки.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat добавил : ) Я только скачал VS, и больше ничего не трогал, немного поучил синтаксис и всё.

Comment: Для студии есть пакетный менеджер vcpkg, попробуйте его.

Comment: Если вопрос конкретно про OpenCV, то на их оф. сайте есть туториал по [установке в винде](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) и [подключении к VS](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо плохо искал, но да не страшно.
Если используешь visual studio, то схема такая:

1. Скачиваем и собираем нужную нам библиотеку (если собранной версии нету).
2. Заходим в свойства проекта и во вкладку "отладка". В строчку "окружение" прописываем путь к bin папке. Пример: "D:\OpenCV\x64\vc15\bin"
3. Переходим во вкладку "C/C++" и в ней во вкладку "общие". В строчку "Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов" прописываем путь к папке инклюдов. Пример: "D\OpenCV\include"
4. Переходим во вкладку "Компоновщик" и в ней во вкладку "общие". В строчку "Дополнительные каталоги библиотек" прописываем путь к папке lib файлов. Пример: "D:\OpenCV\x64\vc15\lib"
5. Переходим во вкладку "Компоновщик" и в ней во вкладку "ввод". В строчку "дополнительные зависимости" и прописываем названия включаемых lib файлов. В нашем случае для release дописываем "opencv_world440.lib;", а для debug - "opencv_world440d.lib;"
6. Всё. Хотя для некоторых либ могут быть и другие шаги, например прописать несколько определений препроцессора или чего ещё, что обычно пишут в доке или туторах.

Answer (score 1):

В добавок к ответу @szabiyako я бы хотел добавить, что есть пакетные менеджеры, возможно после питона они будут более привычны, вот например такие: [conan](https://conan.io/) или [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). Второй имеет хорошую интеграцию с visual studio, хотя и с другими ide и с cmake например нет проблем тоже